# How to convert a column with list to character in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(files=c("A.Rat.in_vivo.Liver", "B.Rat.in_vivo.Liver", "C.Rat.in_vivo.Liver"))
df$Chem <- lapply(df$files, function(x) sapply(x, function (x) str_replace(x, ".Rat.in_vivo.Liver", "")))
```

When I check the type

```
sapply(df, typeof)
```

I get

```
files      Chem 
"integer"    "list"
```

How can I convert the "list" to "Character"? I try to add as.character

```
df$Chem <- lapply(df$files, function(x) sapply(x, function (x) as.character(str_replace(x, ".Rat.in_vivo.Liver", ""))))
```

but the outcome is the same. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change `lapply`which returns a list to `sapply`. However, as other solutions point out, this is unnecessarily complicated.

```
df$Chem <- sapply(df$files, function(x) sapply(x, function (x) str_replace(x, ".Rat.in_vivo.Liver", "")))
sapply(df, typeof)
```

Returns:

```
      files        Chem 
  "integer" "character"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `unlist`

```
df$Chem <- unlist(df$Chem)
```

---

`str_replace` is vectorized, so there is no need to loop with `sapply/lapply`

```
library(stringr)
df$Chem <- str_replace(df$files, fixed(".Rat.in_vivo.Liver"), "")
```

Or make use of `str_remove`

```
df$Chem <- str_remove(df$files, fixed(".Rat.in_vivo.Liver"))
df$Chem
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

sapply(df, typeof)
# files        Chem 
#"character" "character"
```

---

Also, this can be done in `base R` with `sub`

```
df$Chem <- sub(".Rat.in_vivo.Liver", "", df$files, fixed = TRUE)
```

NOTE: In `R 4.0`, the default behavior of `data.frame` is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, so the 'files' here is `character` instead of `factor` (storage mode is 'integer')